# Dynamically adding meshes causes controls to lag

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am making a 3D map in Three.js.

I am constructing the geometry and texture from fetched 256x256 pixel images, construct a `THREE.Mesh` and add it to the scene when it's done.

However, adding tiles to the map causes `MapControls` to lag noticeably, if the user is panning or zooming around quickly. This can be alleviated by using smaller tiles (such as 128*128), but I want to find a better way, as I've seen examples of very smooth maps using Three.js. The controls work smoothly after all the tiles in view have loaded.

I have 2 event listeners. One triggers when controls change:

```
this.controls.addEventListener('change', this.update);
```

And renders the map:

```
update = () => {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
};
```

The other listens for the move to end, and then fetches the tiles in view:

```
this.controls.addEventListener('end', this.fetchTilesIfNecessary);
```

`fetchTilesIfNecessary` then creates Promises, which start fetching the tiles. When the tiles are fetched, they are added to the map and `this.update` is called:

```
addTile(tile) {
    this.scene.add(tile.mesh);
    this.update();
}
```

Perhaps I should mention that I have a callback when the tile mesh gets rendered:

```
this.mesh.onAfterRender = this.disposeAttributes;
```

Which clears the attributes which are causing a lot of memory usage

```
disposeAttributes(renderer, scene, camera, geometry, material, group) {
    geometry.getAttribute('position').array = [];
    geometry.getAttribute('normal').array = [];
    geometry.getAttribute('uv').array = [];
}
```

Is there a better way? How can I add meshes to the scene dynamically and keep the controls running smoothly?

Answer (score 3):

One way to mitigate this issue is to pre-compile all shaders via [WebGLRenderer.compile()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.compile). Meaning when your app starts, you add all tiles to your scene and then call `renderer.compile()` once with the scene's camera.

> this.mesh.onAfterRender = this.disposeAttributes;

This is not recommended since it will be executed on each render call. If you want to free the geometry data one the JS side, use the `onUpdate()` callback of `BufferAttribute()`.

```js
geometry.getAttribute( 'position' ).onUpload( disposeArray );

function disposeArray() {

    this.array = null;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I implemented that proper way or freeing the geometry data.

However, I can't add all my tiles to the scene at the start, as the user can pan across the entire world at a low zoom level.

This is one example of a map using Three.js: https://labs.mapbox.com/bites/00332/ which works very smoothly. It's possible to induce lag, but in general it performs better than mine, and I'm not sure why that is. If you know some good thread or other resources off the top of your head which would help optimising this further, I'd highly appreciate it.

Comment: If your tiles use textures, you might want to load them with `ImageBitmapLoader` since the usage of `ImageBitmap` mitigates the initial texture decode overhead. The following example shows how you use the loader: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_imagebitmap